# set text to textview in other layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

It's a very rare thing that I need to do, but I wanted to see if it was possible.

I am listing in a `ListView` items with the help of a custom adapter. So far so good, but what I need now edit the text in another layout which contains my `ListView`.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#F2F2F2"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Disponibles"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisponibles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/titulo_lista"
    android:text="Inscripciones"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Format listview**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTicket"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:text="" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNumero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtAsiento"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtOrden"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green_small"
    android:maxHeight="48dp"
    android:maxWidth="80dp"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:text="Validar"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="SDSDSDS"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Each item in my `ListView` has a `Button` when you click on that `Button` need to change the value of `txtDisponible` the layout container.

```
holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     TextView t=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtDisponible);
                     t.setText("E-ticket validado");
                }
}
```

The error I get is that the object is `null`.

Comment: what is `layout` and why you use it?

Comment: It was my mistake, it works wonders for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not odd at all:

```
holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Activity activity = (Activity)getContext();
        TextView t = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.txtDisponible);
        t.setText("E-ticket validado");
    }
}
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getContext() is undefined for the type ValidacionMultiple
 - No enclosing instance of the type ValidacionMultiple is accessible in 
  scope

Comment: what is your adapter class name?

Comment: It was not me, I pot in response!

Comment: I know that wasnt you :)

Answer (score -2):

You pass a context to adapter, so just make a method in your, say MainActivity, and call it from adapter like ((MainActivity) mContext).methodToEffectTextView();